# mysql float data type round off's values after 6 decimal places

Tags: mysql, floating-point, rounding, type-conversion

I have a table (say **table1**) with one field of data type float (say **field1**). The values in this field are all unique with upto 8 decimal places.

I executed following queries on this table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
```

The result is total number of records as the query is: `5179`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(field1)) FROM table1;
```

The result is again the as that of total records: `5179`

The above two results shows that the values in the field "**field1**" are Unique.

But When I run a following queries on this table:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

And

```
SELECT field1 FROM table1;
```

Both the queries give the result with values in **field1** Rounded off to 5 decimal places. Which shows most of the values Identical.

Is this because of the datatype **float**.

Then why does DISTINCT() function gets the actually stored value and not the rounded off.

EDIT:

The Values that are rounded off are only those which are > 1. for < 0 values it works perfect.

Comment: Yes I got that...I want to know how does then Distinct works in this case.

Comment: The rounding is certainly because of the data type.  The `COUNT(DISTINCT(field1))` behavior is probably because of how MySQL generates the temp table to count distinct non-indexed records (or because you *are* using a `UNIQUE` constraint on the field).

Comment: @Crontab: Thanks... The field does not have a UNIQUE constraint. It must be the functionality of DISTINCT as you explained...Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you use group by clause ?

Comment: @Sagar This was too much older post...FYI This was to identify how distinct works differently for different datatypes...Not for any queries...And how can you apply group by when floating numbers may give different values for the same number after decimal point at 10000th or more location...